# Python Numpy calculation without looping

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

So I need to transform the following line

```
np.mean([-y[i] * X[i] * (1 - 1 / (1 + np.exp( - np.dot(X[i],w) * y[i]))) for i in range(X.shape[0])], axis  = 0)
```

where `y.shape = (N,)`, `X.shape = (N,M)`, `w.shape = (M,)`
and the output's shape has to be `(M,)`.

I can't figure out which numpy functions to use (dot, inner or smth like that). I'll be grateful for any tips =)

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: yes! It really helped, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach making use of the efficient `matrix-multiplication` with [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) -

```
n = y.shape[0]
exp_val = (1 - 1 / (1 + np.exp(-np.dot(X,w)*y)))
out = -(y*exp_val).dot(X)/n
```

We are basically solving/vectorizing it in two parts :

1) Vectorizing : `np.dot(X[i],w) * y[i]` by doing `np.dot(X,w)`, thus performing all those iterative dot-products in one go.

2) Simulating the `mean` of `y[i] * X[i] * exponential_part` with a `dot-product`, which does the sum-reduction and then dividing by the number of elements along the axis of reduction.

**Runtime test and verification**

Approaches -

```
def original_app(y,X,w):
    return [np.mean([-y[i] * X[i] * (1 - 1 / (1 + np.exp( - \
        np.dot(X[i],w) * y[i]))) for i in range(X.shape[0])], axis  = 0)]

def vectorized_app(y,X,w):
    n = y.shape[0]
    exp_val = (1 - 1 / (1 + np.exp(-np.dot(X,w)*y)))
    out = -(y*exp_val).dot(X)/n
    return out
```

Timings -

```
In [117]: N,M = 300,400
     ...: y = np.random.rand(N)
     ...: X = np.random.rand(N,M)
     ...: w = np.random.rand(M)
     ...: 

In [118]: out1 = original_app(y,X,w)

In [120]: out2 = vectorized_app(y,X,w)

In [121]: np.allclose(out1, out2)
Out[121]: True

In [122]: %timeit original_app(y,X,w)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop

In [123]: %timeit vectorized_app(y,X,w)
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.1 µs per loop
```